# Serial communication design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, serial-port

I'm  currently assigned to a task to develop a software module to communicate with a stepper motor controller. The project is written in C#, I have a C++ dll to communicate with the controller. The communication runs via the Serial port. I'm planning to write the whole piece in C# by importing the necessary methods by DllImport. The key method looks something like :

```
ComSendReceive(pHandle, bufferIn,sizeBufferIn,bufferOut,ref bufferOut)
```

There are several types of messages :

- You send message and expect confirmation (not the same for every message, sometimes it's OK, sometimes it's COMPLETE etc..
- You send message and receive message - you can receive an error or data (for instance GET_CONTROLLER_ID)
- Several other types

Of course I need to control the communication for time-outs.

My question is: Is there any "design pattern" to use for that kind of problem? I'm sure this is quite a common problem many developers have solved already.

To contribute a little - I dealt with similar problem in my last job and I solved it this way :

I had a class to communicate with the Com port and a class AT_message with bunch of overloaded constructors :

```
class AT_Message
{
    public bool DoResponseCheck;
    public string ExpectedResponse;
    public AT_COMMAND command;
    public string data;
    public bool AddCarriageReturn;
    ...

    //Plenty of ctors
}

class UnfriendlyInterface
{
     Response SendMessage(AT_Message msg)
     {
         //Communicates directly with C++ dll, send message, check timeouts etc....
     }
}
```

And I had a class the main application was communicating with, it had human friendly methods like

```
class FriendlyInterface
{
     bool AutodetectPortAndOpenComm();

     Result AnalyzeSignal(byte[] buffer)
     {
         Response response = UnfriendlyInterface.SendMessage(new Message(AT_Command.PrepareForSignal, (doResponseCheck)true, ExpectedResponse.Ok,Timeout.short);
         Response response = UnfriendlyInterface.SendMessage(new Message(buffer,(doResponseCheck)false,Timeout.long);

         //.... Other steps
     }

     //... other methods

}
```

Since last time I was really in a big hurry, I implemented first solution that came to my mind. But is there a way to do it better? Now the device I'm communicate with is more complex than the previous one so if there's a way how to do it better, I'd like to do it that way.

Comment: Is you use a 'newline' character after each message you can use a while(running) loop(on a background thread) to read data and trigger a message recieved event after each 'message'.

Comment: Do you want the communication to be synchronous or asynchronous? In your code, "Response = ...SendMessage( ... )" looks like you block until the response is received?

Comment: It's synchronous communication. The communication has to be strictly single-thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a textbook facade pattern.  The answer to all of this is to encapsulate your variation.  For example, try to create a generic interface for commands that give an acknowledgement, and write client code to use that interface.  Then concrete types can decide how to interpret various acknowledgements into a uniform signal (Ok = Complete = Good, or whatever)

Here's a good article on the [facade pattern](https://www.pmi.org/disciplined-agile/the-design-patterns-repository/the-facade-pattern).  Also see the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).